# Adjusting default value in select when using modelform

Tags: python, django

I have a modelform with an element pointing to a foreignkey meaning its by default a modelmultiplechoice field but i have changed this in the meta class so its using a select field instead since i wanted a dropdown list that contains values pointed to by the foreign key (the foreign key points to a table with categories).

This all works fine but on the form the default element displayed is "----" and ive read at this page:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/fields/#modelchoicefield that i should be able to use the empty_label to change this so a most descriptive/more user friendly value. I wanted to change it to a value that actually exists but the empty_label doesnt seem to support this and when using a foreign key with a modelform i havent seen functionality elsewhere that lets me do this.

I tried implementing this by adding an option in the modelform' meta class like this:

```
'categoryID': Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'empty_label': 'hello'})
```

I didnt get any syntax errors but the default value of the select box did not change, any ideas on why this isnt working ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a value from the field's choices, you shouldn't be using "empty_label" - apart from anything else, that really is for an empty value, so the value sent to the server when it is selected will just be "".

Instead, you should provide the `initial` parameter, either when defining the field, or when you instantiate the form.

Comment: You might also have to set the field to be required. If it isn't required, you really should have an option to choose nothing. If memory serves, a non-required field with an initial value will respect that initial value but still have the empty label available as a choice.

Comment: Hmm ok, i did see an initial value in the docs but when the select is automatically populated with a queryset i didnt think i could use it and im getting a little confused as to if the parameter is for the model field or the widget but ill read more about it. thanks

Comment: The `initial` parameter is for the form field itself, not the model field or the widget.

Comment: ok, so how do i add this parameter when the field is auto generated when im using {{ form.categoryID }} ..i know i can cutomize it down to writing the field itselt but im not sure how to pass the queryset as a parameter to the select element in the template in that case, the other html elements i have been able to customize without problems but i cant just place it between an option value

Comment: There are a couple of places to do it. You could use `formfield_overrides`, or `formfield_for_foreignkey`. I'd probably use `formfield_for_foreignkey` so I could dynamically look up the PK to set the initial value to rather than having to hardcode it into the `formfield_overrides` dict.